# How to handle trigger errors in PLSQL to continue execution

Tags: exception, plsql, bulkinsert

```
Procedure proctest
Is
Begin
Begin
 Forall arr1.first..arr1.last save bulk exceptions
 Insert into table1  (arr1(indx).testdata);
Exception when others then
 For i in 1..sql%bulk_exceptions.count loop

   Dbms_output.put_line(sql%bulk_exceptions(i).error_index;
 End loop;


End;
—other code which i want to try
End;
```

### Heading

I am doing a bulk insert into a table from an array and escaping exceptions through the save exceptions and continuing process. However I have a record which is throwing a trigger level error in table1. Which is not getting captured by save exceptions clause. Any way around it?

Comment: Please post sample code to reproduce your issue.

Comment: It’s difficult to reproduce as we are not able to determine the trigger error reason. I hope it makes sense

Comment: Obtain DDL of a table with dependents, reduce it as much as possible while keeping error occuring, then add that code to the question

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of a trigger erroring out during bulk insert.

- create table with random strings of length between 1 and 5
- insert record with fixed value
- create trigger that throws value_error on that fixed value
- run forall
- notice that the exceptions have both dml errors (Error 1 and 3) and the trigger exception (Error: 2)

```
koen 19c>CREATE TABLE test_bp_source (c) AS
  2  (
  3  SELECT dbms_random.string('x',floor(dbms_random.value(1,6))) FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL < 10
  4* );

Table TEST_BP_SOURCE created.

koen 19c>INSERT INTO test_bp_source (c) VALUES ('KOEN');

1 row inserted.

koen 19c>SELECT * FROM test_bp_source;

C        
________ 
BFL9T    
H6       
DGI      
S        
3L3X     
O        
RK       
X8FO0    
M        
KOEN     

10 rows selected. 

koen 19c>CREATE TABLE test_bp_target (c VARCHAR2(4));

Table TEST_BP_TARGET created.

koen 19c>CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_bp_target_bi
  BEFORE INSERT ON test_bp_target
   FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   l_ex EXCEPTION;
   l_num NUMBER;
BEGIN
   IF :new.c = 'KOEN' THEN
   -- force value error
     l_num := 'x';
   END IF;
END;
/

Trigger TEST_BP_TARGET_BI compiled

koen 19c>DECLARE
  2    TYPE c_t IS TABLE OF test_bp_source.c%TYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER; 
  3    l_c c_t;
  4    l_error_count  NUMBER;  
  5    ex_dml_errors EXCEPTION;
  6    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(ex_dml_errors, -24381);  
  7  BEGIN
  8    SELECT c BULK COLLECT into l_c FROM test_bp_source ORDER BY c;
  9    FORALL i IN 1 .. l_c.COUNT SAVE EXCEPTIONS  
 10      INSERT INTO test_bp_target (c) VALUES (l_c(i));
 11    EXCEPTION
 12      WHEN ex_dml_errors THEN
 13        l_error_count := SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS.count;
 14        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Number of failures: ' || l_error_count);
 15        FOR i IN 1 .. l_error_count LOOP
 16          DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Error: ' || i || 
 17            ' Array Index: ' || SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(i).error_index ||
 18            ' Message: ' || SQLERRM(-SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(i).ERROR_CODE));
 19        END LOOP; 
 20  END;
 21* /
Number of failures: 3
Number of failures: 3
Error: 1 Array Index: 2 Message: ORA-12899: value too large for column  (actual: , maximum: )
Error: 2 Array Index: 5 Message: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
Error: 3 Array Index: 10 Message: ORA-12899: value too large for column  (actual: , maximum: )


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

koen 19c>
```